# WooCommerce Empty Cart Page block custom javascript code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm building a Woocommerce store making my own template.
The store is almost ready and everything works fine, except one small bug that i cannot sort it out, and google search doesn't help either.

The problem is that on cart page, if i click the button to remove last product on cart, woocommerce redirects to `cart-empty.php` page, but the menu of the store that is loaded in header file does not work because cart-empty.php is an ajax based page that blocks my custom javascript script that does the menu toggle open/close.

I have put javascript function script to try to make menu work inside `cart-empty.php` without any luck.

I also tried to redirect `cart-empty.php` to another page putting a function in my functions.php without luck, the redirects is done but opens a blank page instead.

This condition redirects to cart-empty page if is the last product in cart to be removed.

Is there a way to make the following condition redirects to another page that permits JAVASCRIPT to work. This condition is located in `cart.php`

```
if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
...
}
```

The desired behavior that i need is to click the menu toggle inside cart-empty page and the menu open/closes.

Any one can help me sorting a solution to permit JAVASCRIPT working inside `cart-empty.php`?

Comment: Note that *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**"*.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress 3.0 version, woocommerce provide shop order button for previous page. But we put the redirection after cart is empty.
[empty cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcoLv.jpg)

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'empty_cart' );
function empty_cart(){
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'page-slug' ) ) );// page slug or
wp_safe_redirect( esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) );// Redirect to homepage
        exit();
    }
}
```

Hope, it will be work.

Comment: Sadly, i put the correct slug on the function and it redirects to a blank page.